# Php Statement not running

Tags: php

New to php . Trying to run a statement but its not working. Please see statement below:

```
    $coupon_target = home_url( '/authorize?coupon-code=' . $coupon_code.&add-to-cart=406&nyp=' . $coupon_amount );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go enable proper PHP error reporting in the PHP configuration, so that PHP has a chance to tell you when you mess up the syntax like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't echoing it.

It you're trying to set the above, you're almost correct bar one small error, I've corrected it below:

```
$coupon_target = home_url('/authorize?coupon_code=' . $coupon_code . '&add-to-cart=406&nyp=' . $coupon_amount);
```

If you want to echo that out to the page, then you would have to do so underneath the above code/declaration:

```
echo $coupon_target;
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the echo statement as well, this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes usage is not correct try to use following line

```
$coupon_target = home_url( '/authorize?coupon_code=' . $coupon_code.'&add-to-cart=406&nyp=' . $coupon_amount );
```